# SQL Server Management Studio 2014 - Table Designer Not Appearing

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, designer

When I right click on new table, the designer does not appear.

[image: http://www.databasejournal.com/img/2008/08/ds_firstDB_image003.jpg]

Instead I get this:

[image]

Can someone help?

Comment: What version of Azure SQL Database are you connecting to? It might be that the table designer simply doesn't support your version, and so it's giving you a script template instead. Do you have any other (non-Azure) instances you can try with?

Answer (score 0):

Wont you be using Left click to open the table structure? But this seems odd I am trying to reproduce but couldn't with right click or left click. May something else you can tell that will help reproducing?

Comment: I go right click on Tables, and New > Table and it pops that open. This is on my desktop AND laptop.

Comment: The screenshot you showed comes when you try to create table using "File Table Option" but when i am using just New Table it seems to be showing the correct thing